# i can't see title of objects in django admin site .just see this : modelName object (2)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have an app called "web". In models.py I write Income model:

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Income(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.BigIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but I see this: Income object(1), however I want to see wage!

[image: image of problem]

Comment: You need to declare another method, as outlined in the link I provided

Comment: @Adelin thank for help. this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `__str__` function to your model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Income(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.BigIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    

    def __str__(self):
        self.amount`
```